# nested exception class path resource SecurityAutoConfiguration.class cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am stuck with this error for quite a while now. I am unable to proceed further. The error is as follows

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.assessment.assescor.PersonControllerTest]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I am running a test for controller and the code is as follows

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = PersonController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = PersonCOnfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class PersonControllerTest {
    private static final ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        //ong id, String name, String lastName, String zipCode, String city, String color
        Person person = new Person(1, "Raghu", "Palakodety", "45127", "Essen", "grün");
        when(personRepository.findById(1L)).thenReturn(Optional.of((person)));
    }

    @Test
    public void findPersonById() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/persons/1")).
                andExpect((ResultMatcher) content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).
                andExpect(status().isOk()).
                andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$id", is(1))).
                andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$name", is("Müller"))).
                andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$lastName", is("Hans"))).
                andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$zipCode", is("67742"))).
                andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$city", is("Lauterecken"))).
                andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$color", is("blau")));

        verify(personRepository, times(1)).findById(1L);
    }
}
```

I am quite stuck with this problem, can anyone help me out. This is my first post, so please be easy on me.
Thank you once again

Comment: Does the class exist? in the location org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityAutoConfiguration.class? have you checked it?

Comment: The file is present

Comment: According to the [AutoConfiguration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SecurityAutoConfiguration.html) documentation the package is `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.Security` so servlet is missing.